# Function in Query in Postgresql taking too much time

Tags: postgresql

I used one function as left join in Query in postgresql After adding making join with Function, Query is taking too much time.
The tables are huge and numbers of rows are also more that's why function call makes this query too much slow. Function returns few columns which I need to display in my SELECT query.
I tried

1. Replaced LEFT OUTER JOIN with LEFT JOIN LATERL
2. Put function query in CTE and  made join of it
3. Tried IMMUTABLE/STABLE option in function.
4. Tried dynamic query in Function
   However no luck. Any hint ?

Comment: Could you show us the function, your query and the results from EXPLAIN (ANALYZE BUFFERS) for this query?

Comment: https://explain.depesz.com/s/K9Ul                                                               Can you try to access this ? This is main query plan.                           https://explain.depesz.com/s/IBSk                                                         this is function plan.

Comment: And could you show us your code & query?

Comment: Try telling the optimizer that the function is expensive: `ALTER FUNCTION order_history_detail_get_previous_field_data_f2 COST 1000;`, perhaps you'll get a better plan. Play with different values.

Comment: Ok let me try this cost option. Thanks.